# NullPointerException when writing parquet from AVRO in Spark 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I'm loading AVRO files from AWS S3 and writing them back as parquet.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("AvroParquet").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

in_path = "s3://my-bucket/avro-path/*.avro"
out_path = "s3://my-bucket/parquet-path/output.parquet"

df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load(in_path)

df.write.save(out_path, format="parquet")
```

For some reason I'm getting this `NullPointerException` when writing parquet. Might be when reading the avro looking at `java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0`.

```
App > Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:270)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
App >   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
App >   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
App >   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
App >   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
App >   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
App >   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
App > Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
App >   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1284)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:174)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:89)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
App >   at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:145)
App >   at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(DefaultSource.scala:143)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:279)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormat$$anon$1.apply(fileSourceInterfaces.scala:263)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:134)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:106)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply$mcV$sp(WriterContainer.scala:262)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:261)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer$$anonfun$writeRows$1.apply(WriterContainer.scala:261)
App >   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1359)
App >   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DefaultWriterContainer.writeRows(WriterContainer.scala:267)
App >   ... 8 more
App > Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
App >   at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$SerializableConfiguration.tryOrIOException(DefaultSource.scala:217)
App >   at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource$SerializableConfiguration.readObject(DefaultSource.scala:207)
App >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
App >   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
App >   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
App >   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
App >   at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
App >   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
App >   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
App >   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
App >   at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
App >   at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$10.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:254)
App >   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1321)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.unBlockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:255)
App >   at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:189)
App >   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1277)
```

Just moved from 1.6 to 2.0 and not sure what the issue could be. Using the package `com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.0.1`.

Seems to be related to https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/147 but that should be fixed with 3.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems related to my Spark configuration settings as I was able to write to parquet locally and via EMR's Spark settings. I created an issue in Github: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/issues/188.